# big space below Footer in safari

Tags: html, css, wordpress, safari, footer

I am seeing something strange in a wordpress theme that i am building. In Chrome and Firefox everything looks fine, but in Safari there is a really big space below the footer!

When in safari i look at the source code i can't see what is causing this space. I can't even highlight it by hovering the different elements on the inspector window.

When i hover the HEAD or the BODY tags on the inspector window i get highlighted only until the end of the footer. The empty space isn't highlighted.

This is the main css for the footer section:

```
#colophon{
    background-color: #1D2226;
        padding: 40px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    text-align: center;
}
```

Any idea of what this might be and any possible solutions? I'm really lost...

here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot of the page rendering in Safari]

as you can see there is a LOT of empty space and if you look at the scroll bar you can see it goes for quite long space (and there is nothing else!)

New Info: I just noticed that on Window Resize the empty space disappears. I am using Masonry, can it be cause by it?
I am starting masonry like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $container = $('#main');

    $container.masonry({
    columnWidth: 350,
    itemSelector: '.post'
    });
});
```

Comment: Any fiddle or site demo ?

Comment: i don't have a site demo. would a fiddle work for a wordpress theme? I know i don't give much information, but i thought maybe this would be a problem that is known and someone would know what to do...   =/

Comment: How about the screenshot? and mark it where you have the issues?

Comment: sure. give me a couple of minutes and i'll put it up on the question...

Comment: this could be caused by a margin of one of your elements. have you checked them?

Comment: but wouldn't it then be the same in the other browsers? I did check margins, but i didn't find anything...